# Setting Up SSL for SQL Server 2005 as LocalSystem

Tags: sql-server-2005, security, ssl

Due to some restrictions, we have to run the service as LocalSystem.  I have generated a certificate and placed them in the following stores:

Certificates (Local Computer)
Certificates - Service (SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER))
Certificates - Service (SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER))
Certificates - Current User

I am a domain admin.  Everytime I go to SQL Server Configuration Manager -> SQL Server 2005 Network Configuration -> Protocols for MSSQLServer, right-click-> properties -> certificates, the drop down has no certs listed!

According to [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/jorgepc/archive/2008/02/19/enabling-certificates-for-ssl-connection-on-sql-server-2005-clustered-installation.aspx), I'm doing everything right.  I tried running as a local admin as well, no dice.

> unless the service is running as
>   LocalSystem, NetworkService, or
>   LocalService, in which case you may
>   use an administrative account.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Validate that your Certificate meets the requirements listed on the following [KB Article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316898):

> After you successfully install the
>   certificate, the certificate does not
>   appear in the Certificate list on the
>   Certificate tab.
>
> Note The Certificate tab is in the
>   Protocols for 
>   Properties dialog box that is opened
>   from SQL Server Configuration Manager.
>
> This issue occurs because you may have
>   installed an invalid certificate. If
>   the certificate is invalid, it will
>   not be listed on the Certificate tab.
>   To determine whether the certificate
>   that you installed is valid, follow
>   these steps: Open the Certificates
>   snap-in. To do this, see step 1 in the
>   "How to Configure the MMC Snap-in"
>   section. In the Certificates snap-in,
>   expand Personal, and then expand
>   Certificates. In the right pane,
>   locate the certificate that you
>   installed. Determine whether the
>   certificate meets the following
>   requirements: In the right pane, the
>   value in the Intended Purpose column
>   for this certificate must be Server
>   Authentication. In the right pane, the
>   value in the Issued To column must be
>   the server name. Double-click the
>   certificate, and then determine
>   whether the certificate meets the
>   following requirements: On the General
>   tab, you receive the following
>   message:  You have a private key that
>   corresponds to this certificate. On
>   the Details tab, the value for the
>   Subject field must be server name. The
>   value for the Enhanced Key Usage field
>   must be Server Authentication
>   (). On the Certification Path
>   tab, the server name must appear under
>   Certification path. If any one of
>   these requirements is not met, the
>   certificate is invalid.

A bad certificate would be my next place to check for the symptoms that you list in your post.